# get robots.txt with curl in PHP

Tags: php, curl, robots.txt

I am trying to execute a robots.txt HTTP request. For that I am using PHP and curl. This is the code I tried:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "robots.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www.stackoverflow.com'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Nothing gets printed to the screen. Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CURLOPT_URL you must write full host and path

For example: http://www.stackoverflow.com/robots.txt